# Parallel binary counter using T flip-flops

Tags: flipflop, counter

Can someone explain me how this parallel binary counter works:
[image]

For example, if the state in the beginning is 0000, what happens when Pt goes high?

Comment: I edited the post, uploaded wrong picture.

Comment: If this is homework, we don't provide solutions or even hints before you've shown some work.  What do you think happens?

Comment: No, not homework, I'm skimming through my scripts and ran across this. What bothers me is, does flip-flop A ever change state? What I think happens here (which looks completely wrong) is: if all flip-flops are in state 0, then, when Pt goes high, the states change to 0111, but that doesn't make any sense.. I'm really confused here and I think there's just a detail I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a common clock connected to all of the T flip-flops here what will happen when `Pt` is high:
The T input of the A FF will be `0`, so the output (`A`) will not change, i.e. will be constantly `A=0`. As it is connected to the NANDs, their output will be always `1`, so `B, C and D` will flip every clock. So it will be like `0000`, `0111`, `0000`, `0111`.. Which is not a counter at all.

If `Pt` is `0`, the outputs of all of the `NANDs` are going to be `1`, so each FF is going to flip every clock cycle. So it becomes like  `0000`, `1111`, `0000`... Which doesn't make sense as counter as well. So we can conclude that you have a mistake in your drawing. The correct one would be if we replace the `NAND` gates with `AND` like here:
[image]

** The image is taken from [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/count_3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example actually using T flip-flops like the ones in the question.  You'll notice the flip-flops in the example do not have CLK inputs like most do, instead they are like the ones [described here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/tflipflop.html), i.e. they clock on every positive edge of the T input.  Also, the gate feeding the inputs of each T-flip flop is a NAND, rather than AND, so the flipflops will gate at the falling edge of Pt, not the beginning.

Here is a diagram of what happens:

[image]

The A flip-flop toggles on the end of every Pt clock, since it has essentially just a inverter feeding the T\$_{A}\$ input.   So it first toggles from 0 to a count of 1.  I have shown the counts vertically for each state, so 1 0 0 0 = top to bottom is 1 (Q\$_{A}\$ shown at top, Q\$_{D}\$ at bottom).

On the second clock pulse, when Pt is high and Q\$_{A}\$ is high, this causes the T\$_{B}\$ input to go low (because for a NAND gate, if both inputs are high, the output is low).  This is shown by the first vertical red line in the diagram.  T\$_{B}\$ goes back high when Pt goes low, and this positive edge transition toggles B and Q\$_{B}\$ is now high.

The same thing happens for flip-flop C, two more Pt pulses down the road.  Here both flip-flop B and C toggle, the latter since Pt, Q\$_{A}\$ and Q\$_{B}\$ are all high (see second red line, terminating at T\$_{C}\$).  This corresponds to the three-input NAND gate feeding T\$_{C}\$.

Although I haven't shown it, the same thing will take place when the count goes from 1 1 1 0 to 0 0 0 1, Pt, Q\$_{A}\$, Q\$_{B}\$, and Q\$_{C}\$ are all high which will cause flip-flop D to toggle.